# IntelliJ Idea (debugging) conditional breakpoint dependent on other breakpoints

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I want to set a debug breakpoint in IntelliJ Idea that is only active, if another previous breakpoint was activated.
For example i have a breakpoint **B1** on line 10, and another breakpoint **B2** on line 20. Even if B2s condition is true, the debugger should only halt if B1s condition was true before B2s.

Is something like this possible in Idea?

**Update:**

Currently i'm working with this workaround:

1. set the two breakpoints
2. disable breakpoint #2
3. start the debugger, wait until breakpoint #1 is active
4. activate breakpoint #2

I hope there is a cleaner way to do this :)

Comment: [Other advanced Breakpoint Settings in IDEA](https://nirlaor.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/advanced-breakpoint-settings-in-idea/)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do that in the `View Breakpoints...` view:

[image]

In your case you will first have to set a conditional breakpoint on **B1** so that when it is hit then and only then **B2** will be triggered.

[image]

Comment: I overlooked this menu entry the whole time, sometimes i did'nt see the wood for the trees :)

Comment: too bad they have buried this menu and made it hard to find. Favorites > Breakpoints > Right + Click on Breakpoint > Edit Breakpoint > More

Comment: FWIW, You can get to it in IntelliJ 2017.1 by right-clicking a breakpoint and then clicking the 'more' on the bottom left of the popup.

Comment: You can assign a shortcut for this or just use the default Ctrl+Shift+F8 to see all your bps in one shot.

Comment: This is awesome. Did not even know this were a _thing_.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate programmatic approach to debug specific classes when some condition in some class is met.

```
/*
 * Breakpoint helper, stops based on a shared state
 *  STOP variable
 *
 * Everything in here should be chainable
 *  to allow adding to breakpoints
 */
public final class DEBUG {

/*
 * global state controlling if we should
 *   stop anywhere
 */
public static volatile boolean STOP = false;

public static volatile List<Object> REFS = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * add object references when conditions meet
 * for debugging later
 */
public static boolean ADD_REF(Object obj) {
    return ADD_REF(obj, () -> true);
}

public static boolean ADD_REF(Object obj, Supplier<Boolean> condition) {
    if (condition.get()) {
        REFS.add(obj);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
 * STOPs on meeting condition
 *  also RETURNS if we should STOP
 *
 * This should be set when a main condition is satisfied
 *      and can be done as part of a breakpoint as well
 */
public static boolean STOP(Supplier<Boolean> condition) {
    if (condition.get()) {
        STOP = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean STOP() {
    return STOP(() -> true);
}
```

Where you want a condition to set the breakpoint
[image]

Where you want to stop based on a condition
[image]