# How to use conditional break-points in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I want to know how to add a conditional break-point in IntelliJ IDEa. I do not want to know very advanced options about breakpoints, but just to know an easy way of getting to conditional breakpoints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Idea (debugging) conditional breakpoint dependent on other breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607556/intellij-idea-debugging-conditional-breakpoint-dependent-on-other-breakpoints)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-breakpoints.html

Answer (score 4):

To add a conditional break-point, add a normal break-point and then right click on it to see the following options:

[image: On right-clicking the break-point]

For more info, Visit: http://jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-breakpoints.html

- The enables checkbox tells you whether it will be triggered or not.
- The Suspend radio button lets you select whether to pause just the current thread or all the threads in the JVM.
- The Condition lets you speciafy a boolean expression which when true, will trigger the breakpoint.

On clicking the More button, you get to the below screen

[image: Advanced Options Screen]